# Audio issue with Windows me and Windows 2000 guests in VBOX

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, audio, virtual-machine, windows-2000

I'm running two VMs on Virtualbox. Windows ME, and Windows 2000 (2k from now on.) They both have an audio problem. All audio played is extremely choppy. Both VMs have 1024 MB Ram, 64 MB VRam, 4GB HD, and ICH AC '97. Only Win2K has Guest Additions installed (as Vbox does not support Win 9x Guest additions).

More details here:

https://youtu.be/1pEccl1Mq_8

I do not know what is happening, but if anyone who does know could reach out to me, that would be great.

EDIT: In the video, I mentioned turning IO-APIC off. It is already off.

Comment: One thing I noticed is audio is choppy on first logon, but if I logout and log back in, then audio works - at least for a while. Then a reboot of the VM is required to make it work at all.